# How to create a grid in C++ that will allow me to set each index as a vector to later manipulate that vector and then plot it?

Tags: c++, vector, plot, grid

I am doing a project for a class where I have to find the 5 Lagrange points of 2 bodies in space. This project is supposed to be an exercise in root-finding but I am having trouble coming up with a plan for the grid part of this project.

I don't know what the best approach is to building some sort of grid and then have each cell in that grid contain 2 data points, an x direction and magnitude and a y direction and magnitude.

I then want to use these values and plot a vector from it. i.e if there was a cell at (x,y)=(-5,0) with the values (0,-2) it would be to the left of the origin 5 spaces and point straight down 2 spaces.

I am not looking for someone to write my code here I just need some help with how I would go about doing this.

Comment: `struct Vector { float x, y; } struct Cell { Vector direction, magnitude; } Cell grid[width][height];`

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use `std::pair<int, int>` to represent a point.

Default `std::pair` operator= should handle comparison properly for int.

Say each point has a raw value in double. The code may look like

```
typedef std::pair<int, int> Point;
std::map<Point, double> raw_data;
for (int row = -5; row <= 5; ++row) {
    for (int col = -5; col <= 5; ++col) {
        raw_data.emplace(Point(row, col), 10000000);
     }
}

std::cout << raw_data.at(Point(3, 2)) << std::endl;
```